# Get list of objects not response from tastypie Resource

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I just want to method like get_list which can return list of objects not HttpResponse, and without format=json parameter.

I'm aware about getting data from resource through bundle like this:

```
 resource = MyResource()                                           
 request_bundle = resource.build_bundle(request)                   
 queryset = resource.obj_get_list(request_bundle)                  

 bundles = []                                                      
 for obj in queryset:                                              
     bundle = resource.build_bundle(obj=obj, request=request)      
     bundles.append(resource.full_dehydrate(bundle, for_list=True))
 objects = [b.data for b in bundles]
```

get_list works fine, but I need generate my own response rendering template, and get_list require format=json in his parameters.

but it return all objects instead of 20

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return 20 items:

```
queryset = resource.obj_get_list(request_bundle)[:20]
```